# Using the carrot2 workbench without specifying a query

Tags: search, cluster-analysis, workbench, carrot2, carrot

I would like to use the workbench to do some tests but I could not understand how to run it without specifying a query. I would like to make the cluster of documents, without having to specify a query using the workbench. Is it possible?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

The two simplest options are the following:

1. Convert your data to [Carrot2 XML format](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.architecture.input-xml) and use the XML document source in Workbench, where the query is optional.
2. Create a Lucene index out of your data and use the Lucene document source. In this case the query is mandatory, but you can use the `*:*` catch-all query to cluster all documents from the index. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230789/carrot2-can-i-cluster-documents-from-a-folder) has some hints about converting different types of document into the required Lucene index.

Comment: I tried using the query `*:*`, but occurred the following exception:

`INFO An object of a non-@ThreadSafe class org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory bound at initialization-time to attribute LuceneDocumentSource.directory. Make sure this is intended.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZIZZZLorg/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfo$IndexOptions;Lorg/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfo$DocValuesType;Lorg/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfo$DocValuesType;Ljava/util/Map;)V`



I'm using carrot2 3.9.3 version

Comment: No.This happens using the Java API Examples. Using the workbench happens another error: 

`Processing error: ... Format version is not supported (resource: NIOFSIndexInput(path=".../lucene-index-path/segments.gen")): -3 (needs to be between -2 and -2)`




I am stuck in any of the situations

Comment: This is probably because you replaced Lucene JAR with a newer version. If you'd like to upgrade Lucene, you'll need to recompile Carrot2 from sources: http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.advanced-topics.building-from-source-code.